# Symfony 2 - How can I get current route name using bundle JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, bundle

I'm using `JMSI18nRoutingBundle` in a Symfony 2 project to translate my routes.

I'm having a problem on how to obtain the current route name (both in the Twig's template and in the Symfony controller)...

I tried:

In the Twig's template:

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}
{{ app.request.get('_route') }}
```

and in the controller:

```
$this->container->get('request')->get('_route')
$this->container->get('request')->attributes->get('_route')
```

But none worked out... I think it's because I'm using `JMSI18nRoutingBundle`...

Can someone help me?

Comment: What do yo mean by it does not work? What outputs: `$this->container->get('request')->get('_route')` ? It should be OK. I don't think its related to `JMSI18nRoutingBundle`.

Comment: Or perhaps something something is missing in the JMSI18nRoutingBundle configuration.

Comment: `$this->container->get('request')->get('_route')` outputs : null
And my configuration is :
`jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: fr
    locales: [fr, en, de, nl, it, es]
    strategy: prefix_except_default`

Comment: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/issues/125

Comment: Yeah, same problem but no solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok, I found the solution :

```
$actual_link = preg_replace('/\/app_dev.php/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$route = $this->get('router')->match($actual_link)['_route'];
```

**First line :** "app_dev.php" has to be removed if we are in dev mode.
**Second line :** Match current URL with routing to find the current route name.